# Hibernate Second-Level Cache using EhCache

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache

I want to configure Second-Level cache in hibernate. I find out [official documentation of EhCache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/hibernate) and did it. But i got exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
at org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory.buildEntityRegion(NoCachingRegionFactory.java:83) ~[NoCachingRegionFactory.class:4.3.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:364) ~[SessionFactoryImpl.class:4.3.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857) ~[Configuration.class:4.3.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.class:4.3.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843) ~[EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.class:4.3.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397) ~[ClassLoaderServiceImpl.class:4.3.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) ~[EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.class:4.3.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:150) ~[HibernatePersistenceProvider.class:4.3.4.Final]
```

It is not full exception message, but main info.

Below configuration of my web application:

```
private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    return new Properties() {{
        setProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
        setProperty("hibernate.connection.charSet", "UTF-8");
        setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect");
        setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", env.getProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics"));
        setProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true");

        setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
        setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
        setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
        /*setProperty("net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName", env.getProperty("net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName"));*/
    }};
}

@Bean
LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.smartestgift.*");
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

And EntityManager configuration. I don't think thats the main problem here, but i will show it code:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource());
    emf.setPackagesToScan("com.smartestgift.*");

    //let Hibernate know which database we're using.
    //note that this is vendor specific, not JPA
    Map opts = emf.getJpaPropertyMap();
    opts.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter va = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(va);

    return emf;
}
```

I can't understand what's the problem. Why hibernate can't see that property?

**UPDATED:** 
**M. Denium** - thank you! You were right, i delete entity manager and refactor sessionFactory method, now it look like this:

```
    @Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.smartestgift.*");

    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.connection.charSet", "UTF-8");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    //hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", env.getProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics"));
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true");

    // second level cache
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
    //hibernateProperties.put("net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName", env.getProperty("net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName"));

    // testing
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer", false);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.check_nullability", false);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners", false);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

    try {
        sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

But now i got new problem, i dont know how implement OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor, because before deleting entity manager i have next code:

```
    OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor interceptor = new OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor();
    interceptor.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
```

But now i have not entityManagerFactory and i dont know how to make this interceptor now...

Comment: i guess for configuring 2nd level cache you need to be declaring an addition configuration file with all the required parameters for the provider and which parameter its clearly shown in the stacktrace and you will need more

Comment: I clearly understand what error and what about it. It is about hibernate property: setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"); but i can't understand why this error raise up, because i declare this property, but hibernate don't want to see it.

Comment: Have you made sure the `org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory`is available in your project?

Comment: Why are you configuring both a `SessionFactory` and a `EntityManagerFactory`? Both are managing the same entities.

Comment: M. Denium, thank you. I remove EntityManagerFactory, refactor method for sessionFactory, add some code. And error gone away! But now i dont know how to implement OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor. Because before i deleted EntityManagerFactory, i make interceptor: OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptorinterceptor = new OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor(); and then interceptor.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject()); and it is works, but now i have not entityManager. Please write as answer to the qeustion about deleting enititymanager and an answer on my new question too. Thx.